# PHP string with int or float to number

Tags: php

If I have two strings in an array:

```
$x = array("int(100)", "float(2.1)");
```

is there a simple way of reading each value as the number stored inside as a number?

The reason is I am looking at a function (not mine) that sometimes receives an int and sometimes a float. I cannot control the data it receives.

```
function convertAlpha($AlphaValue) { 
    return((127/100)*(100-$AlphaValue));
}
```

It causes an error in php

> PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered

which I want to get rid of.

I could strip the string down and see what it is and do an intval/floatval but wondered if there was a neat way.

UPDATE:

Playing about a bit I have this:

function convertAlpha($AlphaValue)
    {

```
$x = explode("(", $AlphaValue);
$y = explode(")", $x[1]);

if ($x[0] == "int") {
    $z = intval($y[0]);
}

if ($x[0] == "float") {
    $z = floatval($y[0]);
}

return((127/100)*(100-$z)); }
```

This which works but it just messy.

Comment: Can you change this `int(100)` format you're passing?

Comment: Your input strings look like the output of [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php). [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) is meant to be used for debugging, its output is not suitable to be saved/transmitted and parsed to restore the original data structures. Use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for this purpose.

Comment: This sounds a bit like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Where is your array of initial data coming from? There might be another way of natively parsing it without resorting to manual string manipulation.

Comment: Why are you putting `int()` and `float()` around the numbers in the first place? If you just have `$a = array("100", "2.1");` PHP will automatically convert them to the appropriate numeric types when you use them in arithmetic expressions.

Comment: Why not using is_numeric before deciding if return the math operation or false?

Comment: @Barmar As I have said this is not mine - it is a pChart library file that I am trying to improve (it works but causes php warnings which I don't like). I don't want to change the whole thing.

Comment: You said the function is not yours. My question is about the array of values that you're passing to the function.

Comment: @Barmar It is chart data - varies. Sometimes ints, sometimes floats.

Comment: So? You don't need to put `int` or `float` around a number for that. If it has a decimal point, it's a float, otherwise it's an int.

Comment: @Barmar I don't think you understand. If I was providing the string then I wouldn't. But it is coming from elsewhere and therefore this is the problem. I can't change what the function receives,

Comment: The question was not clear that the data was out of your control, it says the function is not yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

$x = array("int(100)", "float(2.1)");

$result = [];

foreach($x as $each_value){
    $matches = [];
    if(preg_match('/^([a-z]+)(\((\d+(\.\d+)?)\))$/',$each_value,$matches)){
        switch($matches[1]){
          case "int": $result[] = intval($matches[3]); break;
          case "float": $result[] = floatval($matches[3]);
        }
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 100
    [1] => 2.1
)
```

Comment: @RGriffiths Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would simply be to make the array as you need it, so instead of

```
$x = array("int(100)", "float(2.1)");
```

you have:

```
$x = [100, 2.1];
```

but as this is not what you want you got two choices now. One, is to use [eval()](http://php.net/eval), for example:

```
$x = ['(int)100', '(float)2.1'];
foreach ($x as $v) {
    var_dump(eval("return ${v};"));
}
```

which will produce:

```
int(100)
double(2.1)
```

As you noticed, source array is bit different because as there is no such function in PHP as `int()` or `float()`, so if you decide to use `eval()` you need to change the string to be valid PHP code with the casting as shown in above example, or with use of existing `intval()` or `floatval()` functions. Finally, you can parse strings yourself (most likely with `preg_match()`), check for your own syntax and either convert to PHP to `eval()` it or just process it in your own code, which usually is recommended over using `eval()`.

Comment: It would be great for the array to be as you suggest but it is dynamic depending on chart data. therefore I cannot change what is parsed to the function,

Comment: then as I said - you need to either parse it yourself or convert to valid PHP code (which also means ->  parse it yourself, so you know...) and then `eval()`.

Comment: This approach is REALLY dangerous--using `eval()` on untrusted incoming data is a major security issue. `eval()` should NOT be used for something as simple as parsing a number out of a string.

Comment: who told it's unsafe or user provided? who told that you cannot do multiple checks prior calling eval(). All this "eval() is bad, blah blah" rant is pure BS. If you know what it does and take precautions is as useful as any other PHP method available. and as I mentioned in my answer - OP still would need to do some manual processing, so eval() is no beneficial here really.  But it's his choice.

Comment: Always some `eval` naysayers, I get them all the time.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski of course you can take precautions to make `eval()` safe. But you didn't include these in your answer or mention them, and there's no reason to assume that the OP knows to implement them. Additionally, I think `eval()` is just plain overkill for something that can be done using regex (like @vivek_23's answer). If you don't _have_ to use `eval()`, don't.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is by using a regex to determine the type and value by 2 seperate groups:

`([a-z]+)\((\d*\.?\d*)\)`

The regex captures the alphanumeric characters up and until the first `(`. It then looks for the characters between the `(` and `)` with this part: `\d*\.?\d*`.

The digit-part of the regex accepts input like: `12.34`, `.12`, `12.` and `123`

```
$re = '/([a-z]+)\((\d*\.?\d*)\)/m';
$input_values = array('int(100)', 'float(2.1)');

foreach($input_values as $input) {
    preg_match_all($re, $input, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

Which leads to the output below. As you can see, there is the type in the `[1]` slot and the number in the `[2]` slot of the array

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "int(100)"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "int"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "100"
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "float(2.1)"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "float"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "2.1"
  }
}
```

You can then use a check to perform the casting like:

```
$value;
if(matches[1] === "int") {
    $value = intval($matches[2]);
} elseif (matches[1] === "float") {
    $value = floatval($matches[2]);
}
```

The latter code still needs error handling, but you get the idea. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

PHP is historically typed against strings so it's pretty strong with cases like these.

```
$x = array("int(100)", "float(2.1)");
                ^^^           ^^^
```

You can actually turn each of those strings into a number by multiplying the substring starting after the first "`(`" with just one to turn it into a number - be it integer or float:

```
$numbers = array_map(function($string) {
    return 1 * substr(strstr($string, '('), 1);
}, $x);

var_dump($numbers);
```

---

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  int(100)
  [1] =>
  double(2.1)
}
```

That is PHP takes everthing numberish from a string until that string seems to end and will calculate it into either an integer or float (var_dump() shows float as double). It's just consuming all number parts from the beginning of the string.

Not saying existing answers are wrong per-se, but if you ask that as a PHP question, PHP has a parser very well for that. My suggestion is to just remove the superfluous information from the beginning of the string and let PHP do the rest.

If you want it more precise, regular expressions are most likely your friend as in the yet top rated answer, still combined with PHP will give you full checks on each string:

```
$numbers = array_map(function($string) {
    $result = preg_match('~^(?:int|float)\(([^)]+)\)$~', $string, $group) ? $group[1] : null;
    return null === $result ? $result : 1 * $result;
}, $x);
```

So all non int and float strings will be turned into NULLs (if any).